# Load ImageNet Data via Spark for AlexNet

Tags: java, apache-spark, stream, dl4j, imagenet

I am working on the classification of Imagenet DataSet on AlexNet architecture. I am working on distributed systems for data streams. I am using DeepLearning4j library. I have a problem with loading Imagenet data from a path on our HPC. So my current, normally loading data method is:

```
FileSplit fileSplit= new FileSplit(new File("/scratch/imagenet/ILSVRC2012/train"), NativeImageLoader.ALLOWED_FORMATS);
    int imageHeightWidth = 224;      //224x224 pixel input
    int imageChannels = 3;          //RGB
    PathLabelGenerator labelMaker = new ParentPathLabelGenerator();
    ImageRecordReader rr = new ImageRecordReader(imageHeightWidth, imageHeightWidth, imageChannels, labelMaker);
    System.out.println("initialization");

    rr.initialize(fileSplit);
    System.out.println("iterator");
    DataSetIterator iter = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator.Builder(rr, minibatch)
    .classification(1, 1000)
    .preProcessor(new ImagePreProcessingScaler())      //For normalization of image values 0-255 to 0-1
    .build();
    System.out.println("data list creator");

    List<DataSet> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (iter.hasNext()){
        dataList.add(iter.next());
    }
```

And this is my try to load the dataset via spark. labels list contain all the labels of Imagenet Dataset but I didn't copy them all here:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = SparkContext.initSparkContext(useSparkLocal);
    //load data just one time
    System.out.println("load data");
    List<String> labelsList = Arrays.asList("kit fox, Vulpes macrotis "      , "English setter " , "Australian terrier ");
    String folder= "/scratch/imagenet/ILSVRC2012/train/*";
    File f = new File(folder);
    String path = f.getPath();
    path=folder+"/*";
    JavaPairRDD<String, PortableDataStream> origData = sc.binaryFiles(path);
    int imageHeightWidth = 224;      //224x224 pixel input
    int imageChannels = 3;          //RGB
    PathLabelGenerator labelMaker = new ParentPathLabelGenerator();
    ImageRecordReader rr = new ImageRecordReader(imageHeightWidth, imageHeightWidth, imageChannels, labelMaker);
    System.out.println("initialization");

    rr.setLabels(labelsList);
    RecordReaderFunction rrf = new org.datavec.spark.functions.RecordReaderFunction(rr);
    JavaRDD<List<Writable>> rdd = origData.map(rrf);
    JavaRDD<DataSet> data = rdd.map(new DataVecDataSetFunction(1, 1000, false));
    List<DataSet> collected = data.collect();
```

By the way, in the train directory there is 1000 folders (n01440764, n01755581, n02012849, n02097658 ...) in which we find the images.
I need this parallelization since the load of the data itself took around 26h and it's not efficient. So could you help me with correcting me my try method?

Answer (score 0):

For spark I would recommend pre vectorizing all of the data and just loading the ndarrays themselves directly. We cover this approach in our examples: https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-distributed-training-examples/

I would recommend this approach and just loading the pre created datasets using a map call after that where ideally you setup the batches relative to your number of workers available. Datasets have a save(..) load(..) you can use.

In order to implement this consider using:
SparkDataUtils.createFileBatchesSpark(JavaRDD filePaths, final String rootOutputDir, final int batchSize, @NonNull final org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration hadoopConfig)

This takes in filepaths, an output directory on HDFS, a pre configured batch size and a hadoop configuration for accessing your cluster.

Here is a snippet from the relevant java doc to get you started on some of the concepts:

```
{@code
     * JavaSparkContext sc = ...
     * SparkDl4jMultiLayer net = ...
     * String baseFileBatchDir = ...
     * JavaRDD<String> paths = org.deeplearning4j.spark.util.SparkUtils.listPaths(sc, baseFileBatchDir);
     *
     * //Image record reader:
     * PathLabelGenerator labelMaker = new ParentPathLabelGenerator();
     * ImageRecordReader rr = new ImageRecordReader(32, 32, 1, labelMaker);
     * rr.setLabels(<labels here>);
     *
     * //Create DataSetLoader:
     * int batchSize = 32;
     * int numClasses = 1000;
     * DataSetLoader loader = RecordReaderFileBatchLoader(rr, batchSize, 1, numClasses);
     *
     * //Fit the network
     * net.fitPaths(paths, loader);
```

Comment: I did something similar :  `JavaSparkContext sc = SparkContext.initSparkContext(useSparkLocal);
        JavaRDD<String> pathsTrain = SparkUtils.listPaths(sc, sourceDir);

        SparkDataUtils.createFileBatchesSpark(pathsTrain,localSaveDir,batchSize,sc);` with `String localSaveDir = "/home/h4/nore667e/IMAGENET";
    String sourceDir = "/scratch/imagenet/ILSVRC2012/train";`    The program was running well but then I didn't find anything in the  localSavaDir